# Caml query To display Upcoming Event From Sharepoint Calender List

Tags: sharepoint-addin, jquery, caml-query

Using Jquery & Caml Query Retrieve Upcoming Events form Calendar List.I use below query but it not work. It display only start date of Recursive Event.

My caml query is:

```
<Query>
<Where>
<DateRangesOverlap>
<FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
<FieldRef Name="EndDate"/>
<FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID"/>
<Value  Type='DateTime'>
<Now />
</Value>
</DateRangesOverlap>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
</OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to ExpandRecurrence

http://sharepointchan.blogspot.hr/2011/10/situation-i-want-to-get-all-calendar.html

Or with jquery.SPServices http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/254560

```
 CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='Location' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='Description' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='PublishingPageContent' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='Category' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='fRecurrence' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceData' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='fAllDayEvent' />" +
                "</ViewFields>",
            CAMLQuery: '<Query><Where>' +
                    '<DateRangesOverlap>' +
                        '<FieldRef Name="EventDate" />' +
                        '<FieldRef Name="EndDate" />' +
                        '<FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />' +
                        '<Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">' +
                            '<Now/>' +
                        '</Value>' +
                    '</DateRangesOverlap>' +
                '</Where>' +
                '<OrderBy>' +
                    '<FieldRef Name="EventDate" />' +
                '</OrderBy>' +
            '</Query>',
            CAMLQueryOptions: '<QueryOptions>' +
                    '<CalendarDate><Year/></CalendarDate>' +
                    '<RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>' +
                    '<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>' +
                '</QueryOptions>',
```